# How are some websites able to detect on which OS I am running the Tor Browser?

Tags: linux, windows, browser, tor, privacy

`Tor Browser` conceals the user's operating system by spoofing user agents. Currently it is `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0`. I decided to test whether the function actually does its job by visiting multiple detection websites on Tor Browser in both Windows and Linux then comparing the results.

1. GIMP Download Page(https://www.gimp.org/downloads/)

   1. Tor Browser on Linux
      `(we think your OS is Linux)`
   2. Tor Browser on Windows 11
      `(we think your OS is Microsoft Windows)`
2. https://bowser-js.github.io/bowser-online/

   1. Tor Browser on Linux

      ```
      Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101

      Firefox/102.0
      browser
          name    "Firefox"
          version "102.0"
      os
          name    "Linux"
      platform
          type    "desktop"
      engine
          name    "Gecko"
          version "20100101"
      ```
   2. Tor Browser on Windows 11

      ```
      Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0

      browser
          name    "Firefox"
          version "102.0"
      os
          name    "Windows"
          version "NT 10.0"
          versionName "10"
      platform
          type    "desktop"
      engine
          name    "Gecko"
          version "20100101"
      ```
3. https://useragentstring.com

   1. Tor Browser on Linux

      ```
      Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0
      Firefox 102.0
          Mozilla MozillaProductSlice. Claims to be a Mozilla based user agent, which is only true for Gecko browsers like Firefox and Netscape. For all other user agents it means 'Mozilla-compatible'. In modern browsers, this is only used for historical reasons. It has no real meaning anymore
          5.0 Mozilla version
          Windows NT 10.0     Operating System: Windows 10
          rv:102.0    CVS Branch Tag The version of Gecko being used in the browser
          Gecko   Gecko engine inside
          20100101    Build Date: the date the browser was built
          Firefox Name : Firefox
          102.0   Firefox version
      ```
   2. Tor Browser on Windows 11

      ```
      Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0
      Firefox 102.0
          Mozilla MozillaProductSlice. Claims to be a Mozilla based user agent, which is only true for Gecko browsers like Firefox and Netscape. For all other user agents it means 'Mozilla-compatible'. In modern browsers, this is only used for historical reasons. It has no real meaning anymore
          5.0 Mozilla version
          Windows NT 10.0     Operating System: Windows 10
          rv:102.0    CVS Branch Tag The version of Gecko being used in the browser
          Gecko   Gecko engine inside
          20100101    Build Date: the date the browser was built
          Firefox Name : Firefox
          102.0   Firefox version
      ```

So Tor on Windows was able to hide the fact that Windows 11 was run instead of 10. But the Linux version was unable to hide the fact that Linux was the OS. I ran all tests with no extensions except the built-in `NoScript`. Also 2-b) shows an additional `Win64; x64;`  that is not present in the user agent. How are websites able to deanonymize your OS? Are there subtle differences in implementation that cannot be covered by user agent spoofing? Is there a way for Tor on Linux to blend in with Tor on Windows?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what's going on, but want to point out that reporting the correct operating system can give you a better web experience --- like giving you the right download link for GIMP. Is it possible that your Tor client is _intentionally_ matching the OS, as a "feature?"

Comment: I don't know specifically about Tor Browser, but as its based on Firefox ESR, I guess it includes Firefox's Developer Tools. With that, you can easily check what your browser actually sends: open dev tools (easiest way: F12), switch to network tab and reload the target page. Click the main request (usually at the top) and check the header lines for the request header (at the bottom) for “User-Agent“.

Answer (score 15):

There are ways to find out the actual operating system.

The easiest is accessing the `navigator.platform` property, [exposed by most browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/platform).

Why not spoof that? Well, there are reasons, things do [break](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1826098).

For details and more explanations you can check this Tor issue: [Fingerprinting: EFF Cover Your Tracks shows actual OS/CPU architecture as platform](https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/applications/tor-browser/-/issues/41610).

Answer (score 6):

I think the reason Windows **appears** to work is because you are experiencing a discrepancy between the internal Windows version and that which it claims in the GUI facade.

https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/o12qof/windows_11_shows_version_10021996_cmd_and/

This sort of discrepancy has existed since Windows 7, which was 6.1 to Windows Vista's 6.0.

So Tor is just reporting what Windows is telling it, the internal version not the external.

Answer (score 4):

**Because the browser told them this.**

> So Tor on Windows was able to hide the fact that Windows 11 was run
> instead of 10. But the Linux version was unable to hide the fact that
> Linux was the OS.

User-agent and other OS identifying methods are mostly wizardry with a lot of historical context, see [WebAIM](https://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/).

> How are websites able to deanonymize your OS?

Your browser "outs" your OS to them. Either in user-agent or in [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/platform). That is desired behavior, as it is usually not enough identifying information and it is not deanonymizing by itself.

> Are there subtle differences in [browser] implementation that cannot be covered by user agent spoofing?

This is a question worthy of a cybersecurity bachelor's thesis. It may very well be possible.

> Is there a way for Tor on Linux to blend in with Tor on Windows?

Change the UA and change various JS variables, such as [javascript - Change navigator.platform on Chrome, Firefox, or IE to test OS detection code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808968/change-navigator-platform-on-chrome-firefox-or-ie-to-test-os-detection-code)

All in all, **you could change all of this**. I don't know why you would but you probably can.

[image]

*Note that OS is not an identifying trait. What are there, 3 of them? Unless you use TempleOS, there are many more people with the same one. For example I used https://coveryourtracks.eff.org to see what is my browser's most identifying trait. It is [JS canvas signature](https://browserleaks.com/canvas). This canvas signature is about 20x more identifying than my OS.*

Comment: The coveryourtracks tool is a great way to see all the things that can be used to track you, plus what specific information they provide. From the results of that tool, you can see that your list of installed fonts is likely at play here, since certain OSes ship with certain fonts preinstalled by default. Tor browser can only spoof that so much, since claiming you have a font that isn't actually installed could lead to page display issues.